# RPostgreSQL - R Connection to Amazon Redshift - How to WRITE/Post Bigger Data Sets

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-redshift, rodbc, rpostgresql

I'm experimenting with how to connect R with Amazon's Redshift - and publishing a short blog for other newbies.

Some good progress - I'm able to do most things (create tables, select data, and even sqlSave or dbSendQuery 'line by line' HOWEVER, I have not found a way to do a BULK UPLOAD of a table in one shot (e.g. copy the whole 5X150 IRIS table/data frame to Redshift) - that doesnt take more than a minute.

Question: Any advice for a newish person to RPostgreSQL on how to write/upload a block of data to Redshift would be greatly appreciated!

RODBC:

```
colnames(iris) <- tolower(colnames(iris)) 
sqlSave(channel,iris,"iris", rownames=F)
```

### SLOOOOOOW!  SO SLOW! Must be a better way 150 ~1.5 minutes

```
iris_results <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from iris where species = 'virginica'") # fast subset. this does work and shows up on AWS Redshift Dashboard

sqlDrop(channel, "iris", errors = FALSE) # clean up our toys
```

RPostgreSQL

```
dbSendQuery(con, "create table iris_200 (sepallength float,sepalwidth float,petallength float,petalwidth float,species VARCHAR(100));")
dbListFields(con,"iris_200")
```

### ONE BY ONE insert four rows into the table

```
dbSendQuery(con, "insert into iris_200 values(5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,'Iris-setosa');")

dbSendQuery(con, "insert into iris_200 values(5.5,2.5,1.1,0.4,'Iris-setosa');")

dbSendQuery(con, "insert into iris_200 values(5.2,3.3,1.2,0.3,'Iris-setosa');")

dframe <-dbReadTable(con,"iris_200") # ok

dbRemoveTable(con,"iris_200")  # and clean up toys
```

### or loop through table (takes about 1 per second)

```
for (i in 1:(dim(iris_200)[1]) ) {
query <- paste("insert into iris_200 values(",iris_200[i,1],",",iris_200[i,2],",",
iris_200[i,3],",",iris_200[i,4],",","'",iris_200[i,5],"'",");",sep="")

print(paste("row",i,"loading data >>  ",query))

dbSendQuery(con, query)
}
```

### So briefly, this is the hacky/slow way - any advice on how to upload/insert bulk data appreciated - thanks!!

Full code here:

- RPostgreSQL: https://dreamtolearn.com/node/8OVIWY2C5RLZZSYD9OHCKM8AI/92
- GITHUB - rustyoldrake/RODBC_AWS_Redshift

### **PS - got this error message: LOAD source is not supported. (Hint: only S3 or DynamoDB or EMR based load is allowed)**

---

Update 6/12/2015 - Direct Load of bulk data at reasonable speed may not be possible, noting error message above, and noted in this blog - LOADING DATA section of http://dailytechnology.net/2013/08/03/redshift-what-you-need-to-know/

It notes

> So now that we’ve created out data structure, how do we get data into it? You have two choices:
>   1) Amazon S3
>   2) Amazon DynamoDB
>   Yes, you could simply run a series of INSERT statements, but that is going to be painfully slow. (!)
>
> Amazon recommends using the S3 method, which I will describe briefly. I don’t see the DynamoDB as particularly useful unless you’re already using that and want to migrate some of your data to Redshift.
>
> To get the data from your local network to S3.....

RA: Will post updates if I figure this out

Answer (score 3):

It may be too late for the OP, but i'll post this here for future reference if someone finds the same issue:

The steps to do a Bulk insert are:

- Create a table in Redshift with the same structure as my data frame
- Split the data into N parts
- Convert the parts into a format readable by Redshift
- Upload all the parts to Amazon S3
- Run the COPY statement on Redshift
- Delete the temporary files on Amazon S3

I’ve created an R Package which does exactly this, except for the first step, and it’s called redshiftTools:
https://github.com/sicarul/redshiftTools

To install the package, you’ll need to do:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RPostgres")
devtools::install_github("hadley/xml2")
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c(getOption("repos"), "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"))
devtools::install_github("sicarul/redshiftTools")
```

Afterwards, you’ll be able to use it like this:

```
library("aws.s3")
library(RPostgres)
library(redshiftTools)

con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname="dbname",
host='my-redshift-url.amazon.com', port='5439',
user='myuser', password='mypassword',sslmode='require')

rs_replace_table(my_data, dbcon=con, tableName='mytable', bucket="mybucket")
rs_upsert_table(my_other_data, dbcon=con, tableName = 'mytable', bucket="mybucket", keys=c('id', 'date'))
```

`rs_replace_table` truncates the target table and then loads it entirely from the data frame, only do this if you don’t care about the current data it holds. On the other hand, `rs_upsert_table` replaces rows which have coinciding keys, and inserts those that do not exist in the table.